# Iterating over inline array in zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to figure out how to do a command to multiple items. For example:

```
mycommmand fileA; mycommand fileB; mycommand fileC;
```

I can do it like this:

```
files=(fileA fileB fileC)
for fl in $files; mycommand $fl
```

When I try to inline this it fails:

```
$for fl in (fileA fileB fileC); echo $fl
zsh: invalid mode specification
```

Is this possible in zsh? I scanned through the manual on arrays but it didn't mention how to do this.

Comment: Just get rid of the `in` word.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$for fl in (fileA fileB fileC); echo $fl
```

Here, `(` is parsed as the beginning of a *Glob Qualifier*, like in `ls *(a+2)`.

The qualifier `f` stands for *files  with  access  rights matching spec*, that's why you get the error *invalid mode specification*, because `ileA` is not a valid access right spec.

If you try e.g. `$for fl in (anotherfileA fileB fileC); echo $fl` you get `zsh: number expected`, because the `a` qualifier is to select by *access time*. And so on...

**So, how to do it right?** -- In *zsh*  there are two possible syntaxes for *for* loops:<sup>#</sup>

- Number one is described in the man page:

  ```
  for name ... [ in word ... ] term do list done
  ```

  So, as [@SadBunny](https://superuser.com/a/876923/195224) already pointed out, the correct syntax of your example is

  ```
  for fl in fileA fileB fileC; echo $fl
  ```
- Number 2 is for the lazy people like me (count the key strokes `;)` ), documented in the *ALTERNATE FORMS FOR COMPLEX COMMANDS* section of `man zshmisc`:

  ```
  for name (word ...) { cmd1; cmd2; }
  ```

  which can be simplified for only one command in the loop body by omitting the curly brakets:

  ```
  for fl (fileA fileB fileC) echo $fl
  ```

  This form has IMHO two main advantages:

  - easyier to remember (exactly one pair of round brackets, no or one pair of curly brackets)
  - works as `for fl (fileA fileB fileC) mycommand $fl` as well as `for fl ($files) mycommand $fl` -- same syntax for literal values or variables.

---

<sup>#</sup> Not counting the arithmetic *for* loops in the form `for (( [expr1] ; [expr2] ; [expr3] )) do list done`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I just knew how I always did it :) Never took the time to research in in such depth, and mostly use bash anyway.

Comment: how to do it without files?

Comment: @theonlygusti: The syntax is not specific to files. "fileA" etc. in the example is just a string.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible. Remove the brackets:

```
monsterkill-ub-dt% for fl in (xfile yfile); cat ${fl}
zsh: invalid mode specification

monsterkill-ub-dt% for fl in xfile yfile; cat ${fl}  
x
y
```

This also works:

```
monsterkill-ub-dt% for fl in *; cat ${fl} 
x
y
```